# Get Postcode and make ajaxcall to API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

im have no idea if im doing it right or not, and also i cant it put it work, im tyring to make a ajax call to get some information from a API and then present in the html, but first i need to check of X shipping method is selected, and if it is, than get the postcode data to insert in the API, how can i get this information?

Here is my code:
js:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
], function ($,Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'CloudJam_Vkios/checkout/shipping/pickup-points'
        },
        getKiosPoints: function () {
            var postalCode = "4433-137"
              $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3h');
                    },
                    url: '...API/GetServiceDeliveryPoints',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',

                    async: true, 
                    //json object to sent to the authentication url
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                     "PostalCodeOrLocality": postalCode,
                     "Latitude": 0,
                     "Longitude": 0,
                     "SortOrder": 0
                    }),
                    success: function (data) { 
                        if(data.statusCode == 200){ 

                            var locations = data.response;

                            return locations;
                        } 
                    },
                    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        return errorThrown;
                    }
                 })

        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

Localizações

Answer (score 0):

```
   define section
<!-- code to get zip code -->
  var zipCode = quote.shippingAddress._latestValue.postcode;

create quote Object : 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote' ( Add in define section)

 define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
 ], function ($,Component,quote) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'CloudJam_Vkios/checkout/shipping/pickup-points'
    },
    getKiosPoints: function () {
        var postalCode = quote.shippingAddress._latestValue.postcode
          $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3h');
                },
                url: '...API/GetServiceDeliveryPoints',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',

                async: true, 
                //json object to sent to the authentication url
                data: JSON.stringify({
                 "PostalCodeOrLocality": postalCode,
                 "Latitude": 0,
                 "Longitude": 0,
                 "SortOrder": 0
                }),
                success: function (data) { 
                    if(data.statusCode == 200){ 

                        var locations = data.response;

                        return locations;
                    } 
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    return errorThrown;
                }
             })

    }
});
```

});

I hope this may help you out.

Comment: hello Sairam, thanks for the help, works perfectlly, just one detail,  how can i bind to postcode, for example i only can get the postcode if it was already filled when the page is loaded, but for example, when i change the postcode, i notice the shipping methods block updates, but the selectbox keeps the same, it doesnt update on run time. am i misisng something?

Comment: I'm not sure try to trigger event on selecting checkbox